# Method from other route affects current route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have to 2 router view - `Home.vue` and `List.vue`. Home is the index and list is the other page.

From home I navigate to list page, then I have a method that displays 10 items.

```
scrolled() {

    var self = this

    var pageHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight,
        scrollPosition = 
            window.scrollY
            || window.pageYOffset 
            || document.body.scrollTop + (document
            .documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop || 0);

    if (pageHeight <= windowHeight + scrollPosition) {

        // code to display data
        self.currentPage = self.currentPage + 1
        self.getGameHistory(self.currentPage)

    }
}
```

If scrolled to the bottom it will display 10 new items. Going back to home page the method is still working upon scrolling. I don't why it happens.

**Is there a way to disable that method upon changing to other route?**

Comment: You need to show some code for us to help...

Comment: Add a code snippet to show, how you register the scrolled method with the window object.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you are using scrolled event listener on `window` object using your `mounted()` lifecycle method, **you must de-register the global event listener** on `window` object:

```
const opts =  {
    mounted() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrolled);
    },

    beforeDestroy() {
        // UN-REGISTER THE GLOBAL HANDLER BEFORE COMPONENT IS DESTROYED
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrolled);
    },
    method: {
        scrolled() {
            /* Your Logic */
        }
    }
};
```